# Silverstripe login/logout

Tags: php, authentication, logout, silverstripe

I found that it is possible to programaticaly put login/logout buttons in header (in Silverstripe CMS) with this code.

```
<% if CurrentMember %> 
 <a href="/Security/login">Log in</a>
<% else %> 
 <a href="/Security/logout">Log out</a>
<% end_if %>
```

If I put "/Security/login" and "/Security/logout" in page name then it works, But if I put it in page template Page.ss then I cant see it (after sitename/dev/build and sitename/?flish=all)

Can someone help with Silverstripe 3.1 and "simple" template

Comment: what do you want to do? have a */login* and */logout* page (without *Security*)?

Comment: I would like to put login and logout button in header or below the menu. Another option is to customize memberprofile module to show login/logout option in header or under the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coming from your comment I would recommend you to just add a redirector page at the right point in the SiteTree and refer to the "Security"-controller with e.g. *sitename/Security/Login*.

Comment: Its not code you would write. Its just creating a page in the "Pages" section of the CMS. So I am not sure how to show code for this.

Comment: Do you know how to add pages?

Comment: yes I konow how to add page, i just thought i need to code something?! I am wondering how to put that functionality in buton, and place that button in header of the page (or bellow the header) I have normal login/register page with user registration module

Comment: Can take a screenshot of the part where you want to put the button?

Comment: yes, I marked with red 3 possible locations.
http://s16.postimg.org/mbz79ezrp/Screenshot_from_2015_01_13_00_16_47.png

Comment: For those locations you won't need to tweak the menu as I described it before. You just need to go into the header/navigation SS file, add the code you got and move it with CSS.

Comment: you can add it in your answer (which code and where) because I did that and I got white screen.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I have created a link to the log in page:
I placed the following code in my footer.

The back slash before Security is used instead of a forward slash, so that you wont have two forward slashes as one is automatically set by $absoluteBaseURL

```
<li><a href="$absoluteBaseURL\Security/login">Log In</a></li>
```